# How to check/filter uppercase words alone from a string using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-4.0

How to check/filter uppercase words alone from a string using C#?
I don't want to use "Char.IsUpper()" by looping through each letter of a word for checking Upper case for the same.
Is there any way very simple code to accomplish this task? with LINQ etc.?

Comment: string str ="iAMsuKUMAR"; and you want string answer ="AMKUMAR" ?? like this ?

Comment: @Sangram - I'm pretty sure he wants whole uppercase words, but it's not to obvious from the question.

Comment: @ Øyvind Knobloch-Bråthen : yeh..u r right....he wants us to Guess all the things :-)

Comment: Yup! A shame actually. Let's hope he shapes up :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What about this?

```
string test = "This IS a STRING";
var upperCaseWords = test.Split(' ').Where( w => w == w.ToUpper());
```

upperCaseWords now contain all upper case words in the string.

Comment: can you explain me the " .Where( w => w == w.ToUpper()); " ? why using like this if i try your code it shows error"System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereArrayIterator`1[System.String]". Please help me..

Comment: Prince Antony G - If you try to just do `upperCaseWords.ToString()`, it will give this result as `System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereArrayIterator`1[System.String]` is the type of `upperCaseWords`, however this is not an error. Why did you think it was? Try the following to get the respective words (if this is an console application for example `foreach( string s in upperCaseWords ) { Console.WriteLines(s); }`. This will write the uppercase words on separate lines.

Comment: the problem with this is it counts all numbers and symbols as uppercase words.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Regex:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string input = "hello hi HELLO hi HI";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(" " + input + " ", @" [A-Z]* ");
foreach (Match m in matches)
{
    MessageBox.Show(m.Value);
}
```

Edit: To handle the case where the first/last word is all caps, you could just add a space to each side of the input string. I've updated the example above.

Answer (score 1):

Using ordinal string comparison makes the comparison faster: unicode, byte per byte without  of culture-specific checks.

```
// the TEST string
var result = input
    .Split(' ')
    .Where(w => String.Equals(w, w.ToUpper(), StringComparison.Ordinal));
// TEST
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean: [String.ToUpper()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.toupper%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) ?

**Edit:** Ok, sorry I misunderstood the question.

Comment: No. I want to check/filter uppercase words from string using C#.

Answer (score 0):

You want just uppercase words from a string, huh?

Maybe something like this?

```
var upperCaseWords = from w in Regex.Split(text, @"\s+")
                     where char.IsUpper(w[0])
                     select w;
```

If you want words that are in ALL uppercase letters (like THIS), you can use basically the same approach, only with a different predicate:

```
var upperCaseWords = from w in Regex.Split(text, @"\s+")
                     where w.All(c => char.IsUpper(c))
                     select w;
```

Comment: This just gives words starting with an uppercase character

Comment: @Cameron: That's what I had thought the OP meant by "uppercase word"; judging from the other responses, I'm in the minority with that interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Regex: http://oreilly.com/windows/archive/csharp-regular-expressions.html

Find all words where initial letter is uppercase

```
string t17 = "This is A Test of Initial Caps";
string p17 = @"(\b[^\Wa-z0-9_][^\WA-Z0-9_]*\b)";
MatchCollection mc17 = Regex.Matches(t17, p17);
```

Finding All Caps Words

```
string t15 = "This IS a Test OF ALL Caps";
string p15 = @"(\b[^\Wa-z0-9_]+\b)";
MatchCollection mc15 = Regex.Matches(t15, p15);
```